# There is a non artinian semi-primary ring?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, artinian

A ring $R$ is called **semi-primary** if $R/J(R)$ is semisimple and $J(R)$ is nilpotent (with $J(R)$ its Jacobson radical).

I've been trying to find some example of non-artinian semi-primary rings but I can't figure it out.

Is there some book where I can find examples or hint to build-up one of this rare rings?

Comment: Here is [the DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=20&L=63l) for that, which finds two such commutative examples as of today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the ring $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]/I$, where $K$ is a field and $I$ is the ideal generated by all products $x_ix_j$ where $i$ and $j$ are (possibly equal) positive integers. Then, this ring is a local ring whose unique maximal ideal $\mathbf{m}$ is the ideal $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$, which is nilpotent since the product of any two elements of $\mathbf{m}$ is zero. Of course, the unique maximal ideal is also the Jacobson radical, and the quotient ring is isomorphic to $K$, which is a field and hence semisimple.

Since $\mathbf{m}$ is not a finitely generated ideal, the ring $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]/I$ is not Noetherian. Hence, by the Hopkins–Levitzki theorem, it cannot be Artinian either. In fact, the same theorem also shows that any example must also be non-Noetherian.

Comment: The last paragraph is interesting to mention, but in case anyone was wanting a more elementary argument about nonArtinian-ness, it is trivial that $I_n=(\{x_j\mid j\geq n\})$ produces memebers of an infinite strictly descending chain of ideals.

Comment: Yes, that's right! such a nice argument.